# Google App Script UiApp when button pressed change it's color immediately before processing script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want script when button is pressed change its color immediately but actually it's change it's color after script of copyProject is completed, copyProject function takes around 40 second

I have thought to split handler function to make it change color on press and before running copyProject Function, any ideas ?

```
 function copyProject(e)
 {
     var app=UiApp.getActiveApplication();
     var button=app.getElementById("button");
     process(app,button);
     var sourceProjectID=e.parameter.id;
     copProject(sourceProjectID);
     return app.close();
 }


 function process(app,button)
 { 
     button.setStyleAttribute("color", "red").setText("Processing");
     return app;  
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a Client Server and a serverHandler on a button that simulates the behavior you want : the button changes color when you click it ... after the long serverHandler function it shows a message.

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('test');
  var cHandler = app.createClientHandler();
  var btn = app.createButton('click this button').addClickHandler(handler).addClickHandler(cHandler);
  cHandler.forEventSource().setStyleAttributes({'color':'red'})
  app.add(btn);
  return app
}

function test(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel('operation completed'));
  Utilities.sleep(4000);
  return app;
}
```

Live test [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw5rQbzYZc3Y9dIC99XPS1KWm9pP6J0H7y80qrv8SzLqScm0hKK/exec)

Comment: Good start, however most of these functions are deprecated now (end 2017)

Answer (score 0):

Processing happens on the server, thus it will only redraw the app after the process is complete and your UI will not be responsive.

The proper way to work with the UI and make it responsive is to use client handler which enable you update your UI on the fly.  Also look into validators, which are useful to validate inputs before you process them without going to the server.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp#ClientHandlers

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp#Validators

Let me know if I can help you further